# Modifying the file contents of a zipfile entry

Tags: groovy, zip

I would like to update the contents of text file located inside a zipfile.

I cannot find out how to do this, and the code below is not working properly.

May thanks for any help!!

```
import java.util.zip.ZipFile
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream

String zipFileFullPath = "C:/path/to/myzipfile/test.zip"

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFileFullPath) 
ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry ( "someFile.txt" )

if(entry){
    InputStream input = zipFile.getInputStream(entry)
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"))

    String s = null
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer()

    while ((s=br.readLine())!=null){
         sb.append(s)
    }

    sb.append("adding some text..")


     ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileFullPath))
     out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("someFile.txt"));

     int length


     InputStream fin = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF8"))

     while((length = fin.read(sb)) > 0)
     {
            out.write(sb, 0, length)
     }             

     out.closeEntry()

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just some slight modifications to @Opal's answer, I've just:

- used groovy methods where possible
- packaged in a method

*Groovy Snippet*

```
void updateZipEntry(String zipFile, String zipEntry, String newContent){
    def zin = new ZipFile(zipFile)
    def tmp = File.createTempFile("temp_${System.nanoTime()}", '.zip')
    tmp.withOutputStream { os ->
        def zos = new ZipOutputStream(os)
        zin.entries().each { entry ->
            def isReplaced = entry.name == zipEntry
            zos.putNextEntry(isReplaced ? new ZipEntry(zipEntry) : entry)
            zos << (isReplaced ? newContent.getBytes('UTF8') : zin.getInputStream(entry).bytes )
            zos.closeEntry()
        }
        zos.close()
    }
    zin.close()
    assert new File(zipFile).delete()
    tmp.renameTo(zipFile)
}
```

*Usage*

```
updateZipEntry('/tmp/file.zip', 'META-INF/web.xml', '<foobar>new content!</foobar>')
```

Answer (score 3):

What exactly isn't working? Is there any exception thrown?

As far as I know it's not possible to modify a zip file *in situ*. The following script rewrites the file and if desired entry is processed - modifies it.

```
import java.util.zip.*

def zipIn = new File('lol.zip')
def zip = new ZipFile(zipIn)
def zipTemp = File.createTempFile('out', 'zip')
zipTemp.deleteOnExit()
def zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipTemp))
def toModify = 'lol.txt'

for(e in zip.entries()) {
    if(!e.name.equalsIgnoreCase(toModify)) {
        zos.putNextEntry(e)
        zos << zip.getInputStream(e).bytes
    } else {
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(toModify))
        zos << 'lollol\n'.bytes
    }
    zos.closeEntry()
}

zos.close()
zipIn.delete()
zipTemp.renameTo(zipIn)
```

**UPDATE**

I wasn't right. It's possible to modify zip file *in situ*, but Your solution will *omit* other files that were zipped. The output file will contain only one single file - the file You wanted to modify. I also suppose that You file was corrupted because of not invoking `close()` on `out`.

Below is You script slightly modified (more groovier):

```
import java.util.zip.*

def zipFileFullPath = 'lol.zip'
def zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFileFullPath) 
def entry = zipFile.getEntry('lol.txt')

if(entry) {
   def input = zipFile.getInputStream(entry)
   def br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, 'UTF-8'))
   def sb = new StringBuffer()

   sb << br.text
   sb << 'adding some text..'

   def out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileFullPath))
   out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry('lol.txt'))

   out << sb.toString().getBytes('UTF8')
   out.closeEntry()
   out.close()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Opal. Your first solution looks great, but for some reason nothing happens, the zipfile appears not to be changed at all.

Comment: The zip file does not get deleted. The temp file looks ok.

Comment: I've tested in on Mac OS. Please let me know if it solved the problem. I may check once again.

Comment: The zipIn.delete() returns false, don't know why it is not possible to delete this file.

Comment: The file is still locked by the code before the delete() is called. Why?

Comment: As I see You're using Win OS and it's problematic to delete file. See: stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java or stackoverflow.com/questions/13685592/… or stackoverflow.com/questions/16985453/…. There are many SO questions and answers about this problem which seems different to originally asked question.